# Issue with scope of variables in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

I seem to be struggling to understand the scope of variables in javascript.

I have the following code:

```
for (var i =2; i< 5;i++){
    var k = (i+1).toString()
    window['graph.point'+i].onMove = function(x,y){
        return [min(x,window['graph.point'+k].coord[0]],f(min(x,window['graph.point'+k].coord[0]))]}
    }
}
```

This code is supposed to put some constraints on the possible locations of some movable points I have on a graph.  The problem seems to be that when the graph.point objects check to see if the constrain is satisfied, they use the last value of k, which is 6.  How do I make sure these objects use the value of k that they are supposed to?

Comment: You have an extra end curly bracket in there

Comment: Read up on the difference between function expressions and function declarations. Define your function within a closure to preserve the scope.

Comment: @Cecchi: Function definitions and closures don't create scope. Only a function execution creates scope.

Comment: Correct you are, my mistake with the terminology. What I meant to say is to return the function from a self-executing function... which is certainly different than a closure, thanks for the correction.

Comment: \@ Felix:  it appears that you are correct.  Should I delete this post?

Answer (score 1):

`for` blocks don't have their own variable scope so you need to create a new scope with an immediate function:

```
for (var i =2; i< 5;i++){
    var k = (i+1).toString();
    (function(k, i) {
        window['graph.point'+i].onMove = function(x,y){
            return [min(x,window['graph.point'+k].coord[0]],f(min(x,window['graph.point'+k].coord[0]))]}
        }
    })(k, i);
}
```

Comment: Also, this is an excellent resource to explain references within loops (and much more): http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.closures

Comment: You wouldn't need to make a function(i,k) and apply to (i,k)?

Comment: @StevenGubkin Good point; edited. Thanks Steven.

Comment: I tried out the code both ways and it doesn't work

Comment: What problem are you seeing?  The statement with the `return` is messed up syntactically, but I'm not sure what you intended there.

Comment: whoops, not sure how that return got there.